# Measure-Object -sum all counterSamples from continuous get-counter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, performancecounter, powershell-1.0

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will continuously poll a performance counter every N seconds then sum the values returned by the counter. 
My end goal is to have results for a dozen or so counters get rolled  up and shipped off to a Graphite server for monitoring and reporting.

so far this is what I have cobbled together for a particular counter, i'm just not sure how to get a couple of things in the land of PowerShell magic voodoo.

1. I can't figure out how to get the Job ID as an integer so I can automate the while loop.
2. Return only CounterSample data from Receive-Job that can be piped to Measure-Object to get a sum.

   ```
   Start-Job {Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(MyNic)\Bytes Received/sec" -Continuous -SampleRate 1}

   while ($true) { 
           start-sleep -s 10
           Receive-Job -id N
   }
   ```

I would also love to know a simple or effective way to dynamically determine the active NIC on a windows box in PowerShell v1.0 or v2.0. "\Network Interface(*)\" works but gives me everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding #1, grab the InstanceId returned from `Start-Job`.  You can use that later to refer to the job e.g.:

```
$job = Start-Job ...
```

And for #2, add an extra foreach at the end e.g.:

```
$job = start-job {Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller)\Bytes Total/sec" -Continuous -SampleInterval 1 | Foreach {$_.CounterSamples}}
```

Then sum the data like so:

```
Receive-Job $job | Measure CookedValue -Sum
```

Comment: First part work perfectly. Now to learn the variable changes that happen with wrapping commands in {}. I did find by RTFM that you have to pass -sum -Average etc to get those values.

Comment: Updated to sum the values rather than just count data points.