# Start-Job of Get-Counter paths from array

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

As a follow up to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910996/measure-object-sum-all-countersamples-from-continuous-get-counter) I would like to compile a list of perfmon counters that are spawned and continuously sampled(`-Continuous`) at 1 second interval (default) with `Start-Job`, sleep for 60 seconds then run `Receive-job` to get the past 60-seconds of stats (`-Average, -Sum, -Minimum, -Maximum`).

The problem I'm having now is the job starts and stays in a "running" state when I use then absolute counter path. If I try to iterate through an array of performance counter strings the  job state goes to "Completed".

Here are two code samples that show non-working and working results.

Doesn't work. Job state Completes even though -Continuous is set. No errors are raised.

```
$jobs=@{}
$counters=@("\Processor(*)\% Processor Time",
        "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/sec",
        "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec")
foreach ($counterPath in $counters) {
    $job=Start-Job {get-counter -Counter "$counterPath" -Continuous | foreach {$_.CounterSamples} }
    $jobs[$job.id]=$counterPath
}
```

Works as expected, but doesn't allow multiple counters to start-job via a loop.

```
$jobs=@{}
$job=Start-Job {get-counter -Counter "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time" -Continuous | foreach {$_.CounterSamples} }
$jobs[$job.id]=$counter
```

Resulting Output

```
PS C:\Users\msnow> $jobs=@{}
[string]$counter="\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"
$job=Start-Job {get-counter -Counter "$counter" -Continuous | foreach {$_.CounterSamples} }
$jobs[$job.id]=$counter

__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
PS C:\Users\msnow> $jobs=@{}
$job=Start-Job {get-counter -Counter "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time" -Continuous | foreach {$_.CounterSamples} }
$jobs[$job.id]=$counter

__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
PS C:\Users\msnow> Get-Job

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------                  
1               Job1            Completed  True            localhost            get-counter -Counter "...
3               Job3            Running    True            localhost            get-counter -Counter "...
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
PS C:\Users\msnow> receive-job -id 3 | measure CookedValue -sum -Average


Count    : 11466
Average  : 5.20268509822716
Sum      : 59653.9873362726
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : CookedValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the scope of the variable $counter. Start-job runs the scriptblock in other runspace and the variable it is not visible. You need to pass it as -argumentlist .try:

```
Start-Job {get-counter -Counter "$($args[0])" -Continuous | foreach {$_.CounterSamples} } -ArgumentList $counter
```

or

```
Start-Job {param($counter) ; get-counter -Counter "$($counter)" -Continuous | % {$_.CounterSamples} } -ArgumentList $counter
```

Comment: Well that certainly wasn't obvious. :) it doesn't appear the `"$()"` wrapping of $args[0] is required. Is there a reason I *should* include this in the scriptblock?

Comment: In this case no, it is more a habit that I have. But if yu want to understand the differences, see http://huddledmasses.org/parenthesis-in-powershell/